# 1995 Mercury Sable 3.8l - 2300rpm at Starting Of Engine but Will Not Fall Below 1500rpms

Tags: overheating, idle, mercury, sable

This car is driving me absolutely batty. I have never had any problems with it before.

The other day I drove my car to Vegas airport from Orange County (about 4 hr drive) and my car died on me 6 times when overheated.

I had just changed the thermostat earlier that week. Car doesn't seem to like stop and go traffic much.

We took it to a shop near my mothers and all's he did was change the thermostat and put in new fluid. He said my fan was working.

I picked my car up after hours and the gas pedal seems seated different. Turns out I was able to drive my car 10 miles without touching the gas pedal once. What the heck. ? . Got my car back in worse shape.

Had to leave for home but only made it halfway. My brother’s friend took a look at it and noticed that a piece was broken. DPFE sensor and we replaced it. Also replaced EGR and ISC or ICS sensor.

Since getting it back from repair shop it had high RPMs so when I put it into drive from park it lunges forward. Now my hood is dented from it hitting.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Check is to see if the Idle Air Control (IAC) valve is working correctly. Do this by unplugging it while the engine is running. If it is good, the idle will drop (you should hear a definite difference). If it does nothing, you'll need to replace it. The IAC can be found on this image ... It's just above the throttle body:

[image]